# Why does ffi not install on the remote server during a cap deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ffi

I am trying to deploy my rails application to a server using capistrano and end up with the following error after executing "cap deploy":

```
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /opt/ruby-e/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] checking for ffi.h... no
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include... no
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] creating extconf.h
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] creating Makefile
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] 
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] make
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] Configuring libffi
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /home/{my_account}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure: line 2367: sleep: command not found
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /etc/magic, 0: Warning: using regular magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic'
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] file: could not find any magic files!
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /home/{my_account}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure: line 7852: diff: command not found
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /home/{my_account}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure: line 9721: awk: command not found
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /home/{my_account}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure: line 9781: awk: command not found
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] ./config.status: line 1274: awk: command not found
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] config.status: error: could not create include/Makefile
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] make: *** ["/home/{my_account}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 1
```

I hope the excerpt of the commandline output is self explanatory, but i can provide any additional information in case it is necessary.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install awk and diff tool on the remote server. Perhaps you have wrong $PATH on the rmote server.

Comment: yup, looks like path is not set correctly. Looks like it cannot find any of the common tools.
I use rvm myself and set PATH like so:
'PATH' => "..rvm_stuff..:$PATH"
What I'm trying to get at is to include the currently existing PATH var if you are doing something similiar.